# calling function when exiting the app

Tags: android, onpause, ondestroy

I built an app that plays songs, and while the app runs I am saving information about the songs that the user heard (Did he heard the song or forwarded it).

I want to call a function when the user closes the app (full close, not to be in background), the function connects to the server and writes there the info it got (the server part works good and it is not the problem here).

I tried to put the code that calls the server in `onDestroy()` but it is not working (I guess `onDestroy()` is not called at all). when I tried to put the call to the server in `onStop()` the app crashed when the app was in background.

Any suggestions?

Comment: **the app crashed when the app was in background**..please post the logcat

Comment: It depends on the way you call the server. Do you call it it by using a service, loader or asynctask? The loader would quit the service as soon as the activity is destroyed as it is closely coupled with the activity lifecycle. If it is a android service, I would expect it to continue even after the user closes the app.

Comment: I call the server with asynctask.
So when does the onDestroy is called? (if it is called?)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I jost forgot to call the super.onStop();